# Volume unreadable in KVM guest after host volume resize

Tags: linux, kvm-virtualization, lvm, ubuntu-12.04

I have a KVM guest requiring more space on one of it's partitions. This partition is actually an LVM volume on the host. So I first unmounted the partition in the guest, switched to the host and resized my Logical Volume with lvextend:

```
lvextend -L +100G /dev/vg/lv01
```

I then checked the file system:

```
e2fsck -f /dev/vg/lv01
...
/dev/vg/lv01: 244/6553600 files (4.1% non-contiguous), 21374526/26214400 blocks
```

and extended it:

```
resize2fs /dev/vg/lv01
```

before a final check:

```
e2fsck -f /dev/vg/lv01
...
/dev/vg/lv01: 244/13107200 files (4.1% non-contiguous), 21785726/52428800 blocks
```

Notice the increase in block count? All looks good! I can mount the file system on the host and read it's contents and parted shows the new size on the single ext4 partition:

```
parted /dev/vg/lv01
GNU Parted 2.3
Using /dev/dm-3
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) print                                                            
Model: Linux device-mapper (linear) (dm)
Disk /dev/dm-3: 215GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop

Number  Start  End    Size   File system  Flags
 1      0.00B  215GB  215GB  ext4
```

All done. Unfortunately the device can not be mounted in my KVM guest. I tried to remount the virtual device on the host:

```
mount /dev/vdb
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/vdb,
   missing codepage or helper program, or other error
   In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
   dmesg | tail  or so
```

and parted in the guest reports:

```
parted /dev/vdb
GNU Parted 2.3
Using /dev/vdb
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) print                                                            
Error: /dev/vdb: unrecognised disk label
```

What am I missing? I have tried a reboot of the guest with no better results, presumably there is one more step on the guest I need to do before the volume is readable . . .

Ubuntu 12.04 LTS is the OS in both host and guest. Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I just followed exactly the same steps with another partition and it worked perfectly. I have no idea what went wrong the first time.

Comment: Can you reproduce this? Perhaps it's something specific to that volume.

Comment: I have tried every possible combination to repeat the previous error and can not do it. I even recreated my original setup and duplicated the command order from my .bash_history and somehow the guest is now happy.